# Need to pass query parameters to Telerik ASP.NET MVC Grid on Save

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

I have a form where users can specify query parameters for populating a Telerik MVC grid with data.  I subscribe to the OnDataBinding() client event so I can pass the form data back to my controller method. Some example code is below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { id = "myform" }))
{
    // Form input here
}


@(Html.Telerik().Grid<MyData>()
    .Name("DataGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        // Column details    
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit();
        });
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
    {
        dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetData", "MyController");
        dataBinding.Ajax().Update("EditData", "MyController");
    })
    .ClientEvents(events =>
    {
        events.OnDataBinding("onDataBindingQueryResults");
        events.OnSave("onSave");
    })
   .Editable(config =>
    {
        config.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine);
    }))


<script type="text/javascript">

    // Rebind the grid when query form is submitted
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
            // Rebind the grid when form is submitted
            var grid= $('#DataGrid').data('tGrid');
            grid.rebind();

            // Prevent form submission action and return
            e.preventDefault();
            return true;
        });
    });

    // Add form data to binding object during databinding
    // This works great
    function onDataBindingQueryResults(e) {
        e.data = getJSONFromForm($('#myform'));
        e.values = getJSONFromForm($('#myform'));
    }

    // Add form data to binding object after an edit is saved
    // This is not working
    function onSave(e) {
        e.data = getJSONFromForm($('#myform'));
        e.values = getJSONFromForm($('#myform'));
    }
</script>
```

This works great when the user submits the form.

But when the user edits a row, I can see that onSave() is getting called, but the controller method that handles the Update() action EditData()  doesn't receive the query parameters like the GetData() controller method does.  Instead of all data items that match the query, the entire set of data gets returned.

What am I missing to have the Update() action get the query form data the same way that the Select() action does?

Comment: What exact routevalue are you trying to pass to the EditData() Action ?

Comment: Try to add: .DataKeys(expression) to your grid